# How to use hudson to track a single metric

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

We use the [Hudson continuous integration engine](http://hudson.dev.java.net/) to build and test our Python software Projects. This involves a `Makefile` which generates various output files like [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) reports and then various hudson plugins analyze and graph the output.

Im now looking for a way to track a single value with hudson without any specialized plugins. Be it coverage percentage or pylint sore or something els which can be written by the Makefile in a file.

Any suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hudson Plot](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plot+Plugin) can do that for you.

I believe the newest version supports having the data in a Java properties-file, in a CSV-file or in an XML-file (it used to only support properties-files).